# Very high resolution stereo-imagery

Tags: data, dem, stereo-imagery

I'm looking for very high resolution stereo imagery to perform a DEM extraction. The only place I can find sample data is http://www.digitalglobe.com/product-samples but the form does not work for me.

Any idea where I can find the data I'm looking for? QuickBird 2, IKONOS, WorldView, GeoEye, RapidEye, or some other very high resolution source and of mountainous terrain would be ideal.

Comment: Do you have a specific area you are looking for ?

Answer (score 2):

check [Here](http://www.astrium-geo.com/en/23-sample-imagery) form [Pléiades Satellite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiades_%28satellite%29) of the french company Airbus Defence and Space. There is a sample of Melbourne, Australia 0.5 M resulution under- Pléiades TRISTEREO category

Comment: to extract high resolution dem we need beside stereo pair imagery GCP file to the same study area. so i'm looking for any sample stereo pair imagery with GCP file.